# Ubuntu 16 Already Installed; GParted NTFS Partition for Windows; Windows 7 Installation Freezes at Starting Windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, multi-boot, grub2

So I got sick of Windows 10, especially when it started crashing out of nowhere. I decided to run nothing but Ubuntu. I covered my my main drive with just Ubuntu, found out I can't run Propellerhead Reason 8 on the platform and tried to install it via Wine and couple others to no avail. Realized I need Windows in a dual boot set up.

Problem: **When I attempt to boot to install Windows 7 from a USB flash, it does the LOADING WINDOWS FILES and then gets stuck at the Starting Windows screen where the Windows logo animates.**

The Boot USB is set to FAT 32, winusb wouldn't install. What am I doing wrong? Some say it's drivers, GRUB, the mounting software, the ISO (which seems to boot on other computers)... And sorry if they answer has already been posted. I've been on this for over a week.

Comment: Is Windows 10 UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI, then you need to install Windows 7 in UEFI mode and its default is BIOS which will convert drive to MBR(msdos) and erases your Ubuntu. So make sure you have good backups.

Comment: Windows supports both UEFI mode and Legacy mode.  Your follow up comment make no sense

Comment: Windows 7 default installer from DVD is BIOS/MBR only. It has to be copied to flash drive and a Windows bootable file moved to /EFI/Boot/bootx674.efi to make it UEFI bootable. Newer Windows versions are configured for both UEFI & BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

So I gave up on using WinUSB to load the Windows 7 ISO and used Rufus with a Windows 10 ISO in the end.

Looks like Ubuntu 16 doesn't like Windows 7 and will only install the newer 10 version. 
**RUFUS** is straightforward and lets you know if it's MBR, etc. The 7 USB boot flash worked when I plugged it into other Windows computers, but Ubuntu would not load it.

Thanks everyone for the feedback!